# How to do the basic RxJS introduction steps?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I want to follow the RxJS instructions:

https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/installation

I do the following

1. Create a directory
2. `cd` into the directory and call `npm init`, use
   all default for the npm
3. Enter the line `import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';`
   into a file test.ts
4. Run `tsc test.ts`

I get an error message:

```
node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:82:59 - error TS2693: 'Promise' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

82     toPromise<T>(this: Observable<T>, PromiseCtor: typeof Promise): Promise<T>;
                                                             ~~~~~~~
```

How to do this correctly?

---

Edited after comment:

On the [Introduction page](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview) another example is mentioned:

```
const { fromEvent } = rxjs;

const button = document.querySelector('button');
fromEvent(button, 'click')
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Clicked!'));
```

This can't be the full file to provide to `tsc`. I get the error message:

```
fl.ts:1:23 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'rxjs'.

1 const { fromEvent } = rxjs;
                        ~~~~
```

Also after adding `import 'rxjs'`, the same error message remains.
How to complete the file?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a `tsconfig.json` file that contains the following options:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es2015", "dom"]
    }
}
```

After that you can simply run `tsc` in the terminal (without the file name). It will create a `test.js` file in the same directory that can be executed with `node test.js`.

My test.ts file looks like this:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';

const source = of('demo value');

source.subscribe(value => {
    console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: I can compile your file. Then I tried to run the example from the Introduction section (see my edit). Is that a complete file?

Comment: Add an import statement before you set the `fromEvent` variable: 
`import * as rxjs from 'rxjs';`. After that line you can write `const { fromEvent } = rxjs;`.

Comment: My file contains now exactly this: `import * as rxjs from 'rxjs'; const { fromEvent } = rxjs;`  In the `tsconfig.json` I wrote: `{ "compilerOptions":{"target":"es5","lib":["es2015", "dom"]}}` and the directory is initialized with `npm`. When I run `tsc` on the command line, i get `error TS2459: Type 'typeof import("/home/mzh/node_modules/rxjs/Rx")' has no property 'fromEvent' and no string index signature.`

Comment: My answer is based on the latest rxjs version 6.2.2. Please check if you use the latest version in your package.json file. In the latest version you can import nearly everything from rxjs directly: `import { of, fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`